# Apache Alias subdomain/folder to folder above subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration, alias

What I want to do is to create an alias at `http://subdomain.example.com/login` that points to `/usr/.....etc/htdocs/example/login` so that anytime someone is redirected to `http://subdomain.example.com/login` where they will end up is at `...../example/login/`.

`Login` is at the same directory level as the folder for `subdomain` (.i.e not in the same folder).

Another point that I think might matter, is that the folder directly above `subdomain` (we'll call it `example`) is not as of now configured to point to any domain, and that folder sits in the `htdocs` folder which also is not configured to point to any domain.

I imagine this is possible, but I'm having trouble.  The main issue is that I am working on a site on *1and1.com* with shared hosting, and they don't let me see:

A.  The Error Logs
  B.  `httpd.conf`
  C.  The loaded Apache modules
  D.  The server configured `.htaccess` file with god knows what in it that sits above my web root.

Couple that with the fact that I'm fairly weak at server configuration, and I could spend the rest of my life trying to figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

step one: get a real web host (without the listed limitations, one that you control. You came seeking help from server admins.. we will tell you to admin your own server).

Failing that...

you have `/example/subdomain` which we have to assume (deductive-ish reasoning) is the DocumentRoot or what is served when users go to your site.

Now you want `/example/subdomain/login` to point to `/example/login` on the filesystem (Which apache has -NO- access to).

If you have ssh access: `ln -s /example/login /example/subdomain/login` ... Since you are on shared hosting.. we will go ahead and assume that is not possible. **mod_alias** is not available in .htacess so we can't use that.

The simplest solution is to move the login directory into the subdomain directory... You'll have to justify why you can't do that if you want more help...

But just in case: Failing all else you will have to use mod_rewrite and a backend scripting language to serve the files from below the DocumentRoot. At that point we would need very specific information on the application you are running and are still likely to say,

**"Can't be done in any sane way".**

Comment: I'm with you on getting a real web host.  It's a clients site though.  I do have access to ssh and `ln` works.  Is this an acceptable alternative, and is there anything I should be wary of when setting up?